# dynamic search/filter in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, frontend, navbar

I'm new to Front end design.
I wanted to implement dynamic search box in navbar, based on `{{body}}` content

For example:
In the navbar, there is two link(role, user) and search box.
One link contains separate page with role table.
Another link contains separate page with user table.

So how can I implement this search logic:

- if I do search in role page, it should react from role tables
- if I do
  search in user page, it should react from user tables.

[Please click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abAkn.png)

Thanks in advance for help.